# What is the best approach to move the data from postgres RDS to Snowflake?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, aws-dms

We plan to implement a pipeline to move data incrementally from Postgres RDS to snowflake.  Here is what we currently have in mind.

**Current Proposal:**

RDS --> DMS (Data Migration Service) --> S3 (Change logs) --> Spark --> Delta Tables --> Transformations --> Snowflake

**Drawback with current proposal:**

1. It's hard to detect schema changes like change in column names with the change logs written to S3 by DMS.

**Is there any better approach?**

Comment: Why bother with the Spark --> Delta Tables --> Transformations part?  Just load the data as is to Snowflake directly from S3 and use Snowflake to transform and Merge?  Also, have you looked into tools like Fivetran, Stitch, Qlik Replicate, etc. to handle all of that for you?  If this is an on-going process, something like that might be a good investment.

Comment: @MikeWalton Do you mean loading change logs directly into snowflake? How do we handle schema changes in this scenario? Do we just let the process throw an error and fix it manually? or Is this anything else we could do? Thanks!

Comment: 2 things: 1) you already have to modify your transformations to handle schema changes, right?  2) if you extract your data from RDS as JSON, then you could load it into Snowflake without ever failing.  If new attributes are removed/added, you could then modify your downstream transformations in Snowflake to handle those...but nothing would break.

Comment: Also, tools like Fivetran handle schema changes for you.

Comment: @MikeWalton I did not understand the part "but nothing would break." Even if we load data as JSON and if the downstream process in snowflake is missing the expected column, it would break the flow, right? or Did you mean as will load data anyways with JSON and we could recover from it once we adjust the transformation?

Comment: No, it wouldn't if you are referencing attributes in a variant JSON.  An expected column that is missing would return a NULL, rather than break.

Comment: @MikeWalton How do we detect if there is a new column? Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: A new column usually relates to a requirement for that new column to be carried downstream into your consumption data model, in which case you are likely doing development work to add that data into your business layers and you'd simply need to add the new attribute to your flattened view.  You could do that dynamically, too, using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to review a couple of migration guides below:
https://resources.snowflake.com/migration-guides